# TypeError: Cannot read property 'batchAll' of undefined

Tags: pallet, substrate-node-template

I don't think I have a utility pallet on my substrate template which I installed via the substrate docs.  Here is the issue in github.  https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/issues/4801

I get a similar error message like this when using batch() and batchAll()

```
const ext = api.tx.utility.batchAll([ext1,ext2]);
                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'batchAll')
    at file:///home/examples/mintAsset.js:19:28
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

How do I fix this? I re-installed a substrate-template on WSL and I can't seem to get my scripts to work after the new install.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So, I downloaded the substrate-node-template from substrate.

I went to https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-sync and followed the article to install the polkadot specific chain.

Solved my issue.